# Is there any automated way to check jira Xray guideline?

Tags: automation, jira, jira-xray

I am working in a testing project and using jira xray for management. We have very big team, with lot of testers.
I have setup many guidelines for defects test execution to add labels components etc. But unfortunately team is missing to do some and I am doing eyeball checking on each of it which is difficult
Is there any automated checking i can setup to ensure everyday to check these guideline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by trying to prevent it by enforcing custom fields on certain issue types, like on the Bug issues. For that you can use [field configurations](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/specify-field-behavior/) complemented with [field configuration schemes](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/associate-field-behavior-with-an-issue-type/). You need to be a Jira admin, or to ask help of a Jira admin, to make these changes.

If you want to make a check, my recommendation would be to use a Jira dashboard for that and include a the "Filter results" gadget; on the Filter Results gadget configuration use a saved filter.
Using JQL, you can make a query such as the following one to, for example, get all the Bug issues that don't have labels or that don't have any components assigned to them.

```
project = CALC AND issuetype = Bug AND labels is EMPTY or component  is empty
```

[image: JQL query for problematic bugs]

Comment: thank.. I managed to do this in the filter method. I have added the filer also in addition to that added a subscription, so i will get email in daily basis if anyone miss anything. Thanks for your comment